# Is there any way I can automate localization of strings to multiple languages?

Tags: android, android-emulator

Just today I had to create a whole bunch of strings for 10 different languages for my application. It is very exhaustive process to find translations for every string for each language, I had to use [google translate](http://translate.google.com/) to do it for me. It took me more than 2 hours to finally finish it. Just then I started to wonder, how good of life we could lead if at we had a tool which will automate the whole translating process and generate required strings in required language just by providing strings in one language (mostly English). 
If you have come across something which is even remotely matches my requirement or if there is something already integrated with Android, please point me to it.

Thanks,
SKU

Answer (score 1):

you can create the string.xml file with the different languages.

for example : for English, default value folder, the language arabic create folder values-ar and use that all string which you used in the default string.xml file with different language

so when ever the locate value change that by default the language string select which you have been selected

to use the initial for particular language open this link

http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-4.0.html

see the locates section

Comment: I think you misunderstood my question, I do know the folder structure required for different languages that Android system picks depending on the language setting. My questions is to automate the translation of the strings from english to rest of the languages.